# Regular expression for the following pattern: "One or more spaces between a letter and a digit"

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for the following pattern:

"One or more spaces between a letter and a digit".

For example, suppose we have the following string:

```
"USA 45623
China      12313
Colombia   46546"
```

The sequence of characters that match the desired pattern are:

`" "` (the single space between USA and 12312)

`"      "` (the 6 spaces between China and 12313)

`"   "` (the 3 spaces between Colombia and 46546).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `(?<=[A-Za-z]) +(?=\d)` perhaps? https://regex101.com/r/bPFFuw/1

Comment: No worries at all.

Comment: @nick consider posting your comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(?<=[A-Za-z]) +(?=\d)
```

which will match spaces that are *after* a letter (asserted by the lookbehind `(?<=[A-Za-z])`) and *before* a digit (asserted by the lookahead `(?=\d)`).

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bPFFuw/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
st = '''
USA 45623 
China      12313 
Colombia   46546'''

for l in st.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+(\s{1,})\d+',l)
    if m:
        start, end = m.span(1)
        print(l,m, f'found {end-start} space(s)')


USA 45623  <re.Match object; span=(0, 9), match='USA 45623'> found 1 space(s)
China      12313  <re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='China      12313'> found 6 space(s)
Colombia   46546 <re.Match object; span=(0, 16), match='Colombia   46546'> found 3 space(s)
```

Comment: They want to match spaces only.

Comment: @Toto, ok. Fixed.